# Why deleting copy constructor for member variable doesnt prevent defaulting copy constructor

Tags: c++

```
class A {
public:
    A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    A(A&&) = delete;
};

class B {
public:
    B() = default;
    B(const B&) = default;
    B(B&&) = default;

    A a_;
};

int main() {
    B b{};
    static_cast<void>(b);
}
```

Why does this compile? the copy constructor should not have a default definition, since `A` has a deleted copy constructor. 
What does a default copy constructor mean in such a case?
What am I missing here?

Comment: I have that obviously doesnt work. I dont understand why this is duck typing-esque. Maybe since defaulted in this case CAN mean deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declaring a special member as defaulted does *not* mean that there will be a usable definition. Rather, `= default` means "fill in the plausible meaning here", and that can also mean that the member ends up being defined as deleted, if that's the only plausible thing (e.g. if class members aren't copyable).

The precise rules are in [class.copy.ctor]:

> [...] A defaulted copy/move constructor for a class `X` is defined as deleted (9.4.3) if `X` has:
>
> - a potentially constructed subobject type `M` (or array thereof) that cannot be copied/moved because overload resolution (11.3), as applied to find `M`’s corresponding constructor, results in an ambiguity or a function that is deleted or inaccessible from the defaulted constructor,
> - [...]

That is, your `B::B(const B&)` ends up being defined as deleted. You will notice this as soon as you're trying to make a copy of `b`.

Answer (score 1):

The default here translates to delete I think. Someone needs to lookup the standards document to confirm it. But if you added a line in your `main()` which was `B foo = b;`, you will start getting compiler errors I am sure. You won't be able to copy B in spite of the `default` keyword used for copy ctor.

EDIT: Here is the error I got when I tried copying `B`.

> ‘B::B(const B&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition
>   would be ill-formed

Comment: I get that, but its not like duck typing where it should be an error IFF it is used, or maybe it is :)

Comment: This just means that the `default` copy-ctors can mean conditionally deleted.